# Casting from "Resource" to Collection<? extends "Resource">

Tags: java, eclipse, collections, casting

I am facing a problem here. I want to call a method that takes as argument the following:

```
public void eSet(int featureID, Object newValue) {
    switch (featureID) {
        case LibraryPackage.RESOURCE_CONSUMER_A__REQUIRED_RESOURCES:
            getRequiredResources().clear();
            getRequiredResources().addAll((Collection<? extends Resource>)newValue);
            return;
        case LibraryPackage.RESOURCE_CONSUMER_A__CONSUMED_GROUPS:
            getConsumedGroups().clear();
            getConsumedGroups().addAll((Collection<? extends ResourceGroup>)newValue);
            return;
    }
    super.eSet(featureID, newValue);
}
```

where I need to call the method as the following:

```
                                            FatherObject.eSet(FatherObject.eClass().getEAllReferences().get(v), ContainedObject);
```

I am not having a problem with the first argument. However the problem shows the following on the console:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: de.oaam.model.oaam.capabilities.impl.ResourceConsumptionImpl cannot be cast to java.base/java.util.Collection
```

I will be glad if some one could help

Comment: `Arrays.asList(ContainedObject)`?

Comment: An egg is not a box of eggs,. That is what that exception tells you.

Comment: maybe you should use ```.add(newValue)``` instead of ```addAll(..)```?

Comment: Thanks Johannes Kuhn, that worked